# Question 1080786 on Windows shutdown command flagged off-topic - why?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I'm a bit puzzled as to why my question was flagged off-topic - [Schedule a shutdown that can't be easily cancelled](https://superuser.com/questions/1080786). [now edited to remove the context which was about using shutdown with a timer as a way of limiting time spent on the internet]

The question is, "`shutdown -t xx` can always be cancelled by `shutdown -a`.  Is it possible to schedule a shutdown that can't be cancelled?"  It is about a commonly-used Windows command, and has an objective answer (probably, "no" as in the comments, but there are no answers yet).

Are people just not reading past the context at the top before they flag?

Comment: I already told you the answer is "No" (["It's not possible. Any solution that can be implemented by an Administrator can be undone by an Administrator"](http://superuser.com/questions/1080786/schedule-a-shutdown-that-cant-be-easily-cancelled#comment1528058_1080786)). What more do you need?

Comment: By the way, the voting was Close × 3, Leave Open × 2

Comment: I was unnecessarily rude in the original question - your comment would indeed be a good answer.  I would leave it a few days to see if anyone had any other bright ideas (hard to prove a negative), but I expect it to be the right answer.

Comment: Well, either by losing credentials or......  This would be effective:
  Electrical power timer.

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
What topics can I ask about here?: A specific electronics design problem.

Comment: Also, restricting a user is a security question.    There is a big difference between the security that Windows has in theory, and security from the point of view of anyone who googles about how to get around a Windows security feature.   A computer is built as a tool to help you.  There are only 2 users on that system, you and Microsoft.  Microsoft could shut you down simply with a scheduled update, a specialty of Windows.  That's the best I have.  Nothing on topic yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems based entirely in wetware (such as "how do I stop myself browsing the internet") would be off-topic.  It is also very difficult to read past the "I am the real problem, please make my computer disobey me." preface to the actual question.

That said I don't think this would be off-topic if you were just asking if a shutdown were able to be made uncancelable.

Asking for software recommendations to work around your lack of self control would also be off-topic and would be better on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but I would be surprised if a quick search didn't find a few duplicate questions already.

Comment: Thanks.  I've now edited the question.